# Selenium JUnit 4 test - usage of findElement()

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, webdriver

I have a problem that I can't get through. I just started to use Selenium, and I made a simple JUnit test with it. (Open CMS admin panel, log in and log out.) If I use the correct username and password it works like a charm, but if I don't, it just can't get over finding the "Log out" button, however I've put it into try-catch block. :/ Actually it just stops by the if statement (see the code below) without throwing the exception, and it won't close the browser and finish the test because it never reach "driver.quit()".

If you have any idea about my problem, please help me out!

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JavaExp {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://urlhere.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJValami() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/administrator/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-username")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-password")).sendKeys("almakfa");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Belépés")).click(); //Click on the login Button
        if(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Kilépés"))) { //Looking for the Log out link
            System.out.println("Got it.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found.");
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the matter is that after you press 'login' button page is supposed to render.
So in your case I would try different wait mechanisms:

```
 public boolean isElementPresent(By selector)
   {
       return driver.findElements(selector).size()>0;
   }
```

1. `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Belépés")).click(); //Click on the login Button
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   if(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Kilépés"))) 
   { //Looking for the Log out link
           System.out.println("Got it.");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Not found.");
       }`
2. `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Belépés")).click(); //Click on the login Button
   Thread.sleep(1000);
   if(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Kilépés"))) 
   { //Looking for the Log out link
           System.out.println("Got it.");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Not found.");
       }`
3. `public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
                   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                           .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                           .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
                   WebElement foo = wait.until(
                           new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                               public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                                   return driver.findElement(locator);
                               }
                           }
                   );
                   return  foo;              }     ;
           driver.findElement(By.linkText("Belépés")).click(); //Click on the login Button
           fluentWait(By.linkText("Kilépés"));
            if(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Kilépés"))) 
           { //Looking for the Log out link
                       System.out.println("Got it.");
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("Not found.");
                   }`

Comment: Thanks! With the combination of your isElementPresent() function and method (1) it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you are using `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` which means **implicit wait for all elements**. Therefore, your program waits **30** seconds for that button to appear, and then goes further. Try to wait 31 seconds and then you'll see the results.

Comment: The funny thing is I waited more then 10 minutes, and nothing happened. However, with the function that Eugene wrote it works, so probably the original isElementPresent() wasn't really appropriate. Thanks anyway!